# Background-image stretch

Tags: css

I want to stretch the background image to match the size of the screen

```
body {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    width: 80%;
    background-image: url(hola.jpg);
}
```

I try to put `background-size: 1500px 1500px;` and is fixed.

How I can do it and automatic for all pages resolutions?

Comment: Have a look at css-tricks: [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). BTW, you can only make the background as big as the container AFAIK, so that `width: 80%` will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-size:cover;
background-position:50% 50%;
```

[Not compatible with IE8 and lower](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts), yours to decide whether you need to support those now that IE11 is already out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it should even work if your `<body>` does not cover the whole window:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100%;
```

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size:

> `<percentage>`
>    A  value that scales the background image in the corresponding dimension to the specified percentage of the background positioning area, which is determined by the value of background-origin. [...] If the background's attachment is fixed, the background positioning area is instead the entire area of the browser window, not including the area covered by scrollbars if they are present. [...]